# Chess game using Tkinter GUI, Moving the pieces

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a chess game as the A-Level programming project and I am having trouble getting the pieces to move across the board. The canvas.move() function that i am using doesn't seem to move the images and i have tried other functions including canvas.coords() any help would be appreciated.
This is the code for moving the pieces:

```
 piece = None

    def getorigin(eventorigin):
        global Posx,Posy, piece
        Posx = eventorigin.x
        Posy = eventorigin.y
        Xcase = math.ceil((Posx / 62)) - 1
        Ycase = math.ceil((Posy / 62)) - 1
        
        if Matrix[Ycase][Xcase] != "":
    # select the piece
            piece = Matrix[Ycase][Xcase]
            preY = Ycase
            preX = Xcase
            print(piece)
        elif piece:
    # a piece is selected, so move the piece
            canvas.move(piece, Xcase*62.5+33, Ycase*62.5+33)
            Matrix[Ycase][Xcase] = piece
            Matrix[preY][preX] = ""
            piece = None  # deselect the piece 
            piecePosition()

    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", getorigin)
    root.title("Chess")
    root.iconbitmap()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the matrix grid being used as the board:

```
Matrix= [["bRook","bKnight","bBishop","bQueen","bKing","bBishop","bKnight","bRook"],
            ["bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn"],
            ["","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","",""],
            ["wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn"],
            ["wRook","wKnight","wBishop","wQueen","wKing","wBishop","wKnight","wRook"]]
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is runnable. The code you posted has indentation issues. You also need to show how `getorigin` is being called -- is it called from a binding?

Comment: Is `piece` the item ID returned by those `canvas.create_xxxx(...)` functions? Also `canvas.moveto(...)` or `canvas.coords(...)` should be used instead of `canvas.move(...)`.